# Check what files is 'make' including

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm compiling a kernel module and I'm including `<asm/unistd.h>`, but I'm not sure if the compiler is using the `unistd.h` from `/usr/includes/` (wrong) or the one from `/usr/src/kernel-3.x.x/arch/x86/includes/` (right).

My question is: How can I check which one of those two is the compiler using?

And also, is there a way to force the file from the kernel headers instead of the one from `/usr/include`?

Answer (score 1):

```
cpp code.c | grep unistd.h
```

or

```
gcc -E code.c | grep unistd.h
```

Comment: I think `gcc -E code.c | grep unistd.h` won't print anything because the `#include <asm/unistd.h>` would be replaced by the content of it, which I think does not say "unistd.h" after being pre-processed. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Eregrith, try it, on my computer: `david@debian:~$ cpp code.c | grep unistd.h` returns
`# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd.h" 1 3 4`
`# 5 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd.h" 2 3 4`

Comment: Ok, I'll try it in a few minutes. What about forcing one of the paths?

Comment: @AlterMann sadly I run windows at work and can't try it easily :( thanks for telling me though :)

Comment: When additional libraries are installed in other directories it is necessary to extend the search paths, in order for the libraries to be found. The compiler options -I and -L add new directories to the beginning of the include path and library search path respectively.

Comment: @AlterMann I'm asking for the reverse! How can I limit gcc. I mean, how can I make it NOT to look in /usr/includes nor anywhere else that's not in /usr/src/kernel-$(uname -a)/ ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question:

*And also, is there a way to force the file from the kernel headers instead of the one from `/usr/include`?*

You can pass the `-nostdinc` option to `gcc`:

*"Do not search the standard system directories for header files. Only the directories you have specified with -I options (and the directory of the current file, if appropriate) are searched."*

[GCC: Options Controlling the Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)